# Excel VBA UDF - Fail to pass a variant array resulting from UDFas an input in second UDF

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am struggling with using the array resulting from an UDF I have written as the argument to another UDF.

The function returns the #value error.

I can not figure where the problem lies.

Below is the code.

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated ;)

This one works..

```
Function fTA_GetSMA(ByRef varData As Variant, ByRef lPeriod As Long) As Variant

' This function computes a simple moving average over a defined period.

Dim l As Long
Dim dSum As Double
Dim var() As Variant

    Application.Volatile
    varData = varData.Value2
    ReDim var(LBound(varData, 1) To UBound(varData, 1), 1)
    For l = LBound(varData, 1) To UBound(varData, 1)
        If l < lPeriod Then
            dSum = dSum + varData(l, 1)
        ElseIf l = lPeriod Then
            dSum = dSum + varData(l, 1)
            var(l, 1) = dSum / lPeriod
        ElseIf l > lPeriod Then
            dSum = dSum + varData(l, 1) - varData(l - lPeriod, 1)
            var(l, 1) = dSum / lPeriod
        End If
    Next l
    fTA_GetSMA = var
```

End Function

**This one works also.**

Function fTA_GetTR(ByRef varData As Variant) As Variant
' This function computes the true range of a financial time series.
' The input data must be a matrix containing O, H, L, C.

```
Dim var() As Variant
Dim l As Long
Dim dMaxTR As Double
Dim dMinTR As Double

    Application.Volatile
    varData = varData.Value2
    ReDim var(LBound(varData, 1) To UBound(varData, 1), 1)
    For l = LBound(varData, 1) To UBound(varData, 1)
        If l = 1 Then
            dMinTR = varData(l, 3)
            dMaxTR = varData(l, 2)
        ElseIf l > 1 Then
            dMaxTR = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(varData(l, 2), varData(l - 1, 4))
            dMinTR = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(varData(l, 3), varData(l - 1, 4))
        End If
        var(l, 1) = dMaxTR - dMinTR
    Next l

    fTA_GetTR = var
```

End Function

**THIS IS THE ONE which is not working..**

Function fTA_GetATR(ByRef varData As Variant, ByRef lPeriod As Long) As Variant
' This function computes the average true range of a financial time series over a given number of periods.
' the input data must be a matrix containing O, H, L, C.
' the average formula is a SMA

```
Dim var() As Variant
Dim varATR() As Variant

    ReDim var(LBound(varData, 1) To UBound(varData, 1), 1)
    ReDim varATR(LBound(varData, 1) To UBound(varData, 1), 1)
    var = fTA_GetTR(varData)
    varATR = fTA_GetSMA(var, lPeriod)
    Debug.Print varATR
    fTA_GetATR = varATR
```

End Function

Comment: Use simple subs which call your functions for testing, and use the debugging facilities of VBA. You can get #value errors for almost every reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use VarData.Value2 if if Var contains a range reference: it won't work if VarData is a variant array.
Your UDFs expect Range arguments as input (because you use .Value2) but return a variant containing an array. So when you call one of them using the output from a different UDF it fails because the input is not a range.
You can detect this by setting a breakpoint and showing the Locals window to inspect what the Var variable contains.

The way to handle this is to do something like this

```
if IsObject(VarData) then VarData=VarData.Value2
```